# Installing pip on ESXi Host

Tags: python, pip, esxi

I would like to extend my ESXi Host with some more python modules.

Easiest way for this would be if pip would be available.

Anybody knows how to install pip on an ESXi Host?

Comment: Check out http://www.iwan.wiki/Getting_started_with_vSphere_and_python_scripting_(pyVmomi)#Install_pip . Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Thanks @PedroRodrigues but I want to install pip on the ESXi Host, not on a VM (to then controll the host)

Comment: I believe the intended scenario you want, is not supported by vmware. They expect a VM to handle host maintenance routines and not the host itself. In fact that is what they, used to at least, do with vCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to add the library (s3cmd) that I was after (without pip).

It's not a full answer to my question above, but it shows how you can manually add packages to an ESXi Host:

https://miami-nice.co.uk/free-vmware-esxi-5-5-vm-backups-to-amazon-s3/